# Angular: configure default QueryParamsHandling

Tags: angular, angular9, query-string, angular-routerlink

I've built an angular 9 app, and added localization with @ngx-translate. I've configured my app so that it takes the `lang` query parameter and changes the locale accordingly.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private translateService: TranslateService) {
    this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((params) => {
      let lang = params.get('lang');
      console.log('language', lang);
      if (lang !== null) {
        this.translateService.use(lang);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I then added 3 buttons on my sidebar to change the query parameter (and switch the language)

```
<div class="p-1 text-center">
  <a [routerLink]='[]' [queryParams]="{}">
    <app-flag [country]="'en'" [appHoverClass]="'brightness-250'"></app-flag>
  </a>
  <a [routerLink]='[]' [queryParams]="{'lang':'nl'}">
    <app-flag [country]="'nl'" [appHoverClass]="'brightness-250'"></app-flag>
  </a>
  <a [routerLink]='[]' [queryParams]="{'lang':'fr'}">
    <app-flag [country]="'fr'" [appHoverClass]="'brightness-250'"></app-flag>
  </a>
</div>
```

This is working fine. But when a normal routerLink is pressed, or at a router.navigate() call, the query parameters are lost again.

I don't want to decorate each and every `routerLink` in my application with the `[queryParamsHandling]="'preserve'"` directive since this is a tedious job and horrible practice. There is already a GitHub issue active for this topic, but the angular team is pretty much not working on it (for 4 years already): https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12664

Is there a way (any way) to have the query parameters (or just the `lang` query parameter) preserved by default when navigating?

I've already created an `ExtendedRouter` on top of the default angular router

```
import { Router, QueryParamsHandling, NavigationExtras, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

export class ExtendedRouter {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  private _defaultQueryParamsHandling: QueryParamsHandling = null;
  public get defaultQueryParamsHandling() {
    return this._defaultQueryParamsHandling;
  }
  public set defaultQueryParamsHandling(value: QueryParamsHandling) {
    this._defaultQueryParamsHandling = value;
  }

  public navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras) {
    return this.router.navigate(commands, {
      queryParamsHandling: extras.queryParamsHandling ?? this.defaultQueryParamsHandling ?? '',
      fragment: extras.fragment,
      preserveFragment: extras.preserveFragment,
      queryParams: extras.queryParams,
      relativeTo: extras.relativeTo,
      replaceUrl: extras.replaceUrl,
      skipLocationChange: extras.skipLocationChange
    });
  }

  public navigateByUrl(url: string | UrlTree, extras?: NavigationExtras) {
    return this.router.navigateByUrl(url, {
      queryParamsHandling: extras.queryParamsHandling ?? this.defaultQueryParamsHandling ?? '',
      fragment: extras.fragment,
      preserveFragment: extras.preserveFragment,
      queryParams: extras.queryParams,
      relativeTo: extras.relativeTo,
      replaceUrl: extras.replaceUrl,
      skipLocationChange: extras.skipLocationChange
    });
  }

  public createUrlTree(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras) {
    return this.router.createUrlTree(commands, extras);
  }

  public serializeUrl(url: UrlTree) {
    return this.router.serializeUrl(url);
  }
}
```

But this doesn't deal with the `[routerLink]` directive. I've tried creating one as well, but all fields I need are scoped to `private`.

```
import { Directive, Renderer2, ElementRef, Attribute, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterLink, Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ExtendedRouter } from '../../helpers/extended-router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[extendedRouterLink]'
})
export class ExtendedRouterLinkDirective extends RouterLink {

  private router2: Router;
  private route2: ActivatedRoute;
  private commands2: any[] = [];
  constructor(router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute, @Attribute('tabindex') tabIndex: string, renderer: Renderer2, el: ElementRef<any>, private extendedRouter: ExtendedRouter) {
    super(router, route, tabIndex, renderer, el);
    this.router2 = router;
    this.route2 = route;
  }

  @Input()
  set extendedRouterLink(commands: any[] | string | null | undefined) {
    if (commands != null) {
      this.commands2 = Array.isArray(commands) ? commands : [commands];
    } else {
      this.commands2 = [];
    }
    super.commands = commands;
  }

  get urlTree() {
    return this.router2.createUrlTree(this.commands, {
      relativeTo: this.route2,
      queryParams: this.queryParams,
      fragment: this.fragment,
      queryParamsHandling: this.queryParamsHandling,
      preserveFragment: this.attrBoolValue(this.preserveFragment),
    });
  }

  private attrBoolValue = (s: any) => {
    return s === '' || !!s;
  }

}
```

Anyone an idea how to get around this without having to define a `[queryParamsHandling]` on each `[routerLink]`?

Comment: This seems to be a nice solution: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12664#issuecomment-589980254

Comment: Indeed, I must have looked over it. I'll try it out

Comment: Works very well indeed. Good answer

Comment: It appears that when using angular routing, the directive is not applied to link elements in newly created components for some reason. Do you know a way to solve this?

Comment: What does the directive's selector look like? Have you tried something like: `selector: '[routerLink]'` ?

Comment: Yes. `a[routerLink]` (https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/src/app/directives/query-params-handling/query-params-handling.directive.ts)

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz demo?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-preserve-queryparams When clicking the top links, the queryparams are preserved. When clicking the links inside the routing components, the queryparams disappear. However the url of those links seems to be correct. So it appears that the directive isn't being re-applied to the links inside the router-outlet after navigation has occurred. How can I solve this?

Comment: Thanks for the SB. I'll have a look.

Comment: I'm sorry that was the normal demo. Here's an extended version with the links inside the routing components: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-preserve-queryparams-link-from-routing-componen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small problem with this approach:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'a[routerLink]'
})
export class QueryParamsHandlingDirective extends RouterLinkWithHref {
  queryParamsHandling: QueryParamsHandling = 'merge';
}
```

The problem is that it extends `RouterLinkWithHref`, meaning an `<a routerLink="">` will have **2 directives**(one which extends the other) attached to it.

And [this is what happens](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L203-L212) inside `RouterLinkWithHref`'s `click` handler:

```js
@HostListener('click')
onClick(): boolean {
  const extras = {
    skipLocationChange: attrBoolValue(this.skipLocationChange),
    replaceUrl: attrBoolValue(this.replaceUrl),
    state: this.state,
  };
  this.router.navigateByUrl(this.urlTree, extras);
  return true;
}
```

What's more important is how this looks when it's shipped to the browser:

```js
 RouterLinkWithHref.prototype.onClick = function (button, ctrlKey, metaKey, shiftKey) {
  if (button !== 0 || ctrlKey || metaKey || shiftKey) {
      return true;
  }
  if (typeof this.target === 'string' && this.target != '_self') {
      return true;
  }
  var extras = {
      skipLocationChange: attrBoolValue(this.skipLocationChange),
      replaceUrl: attrBoolValue(this.replaceUrl),
      state: this.state
  };
  this.router.navigateByUrl(this.urlTree, extras);
  return false;
};
```

This means that when you click on an `<a>` tag, the `QueryParamsHandlingDirective.onClick` will be invoked, and then `RouterLinkWithHref.onClick`. But since `RouterLinkWithHref.onClick` is called last, it won't have the `queryParamsHandling` set to `merge`.

---

The solution is to slightly modify the custom directive so that it **does not inherit** anything, but simply sets a property:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'a[routerLink]'
})
export class QueryParamsHandlingDirective {
  constructor (routerLink: RouterLinkWithHref) {
    routerLink.queryParamsHandling = 'merge';
  }
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-preserve-queryparams-link-from-routing-c-eew3gj?file=src/app/directives/query-params-handling/query-params-handling.directive.ts).

Comment: Works very well. Very nice and swift solution. Thanks for the in-depth answer.

Comment: It was my pleasure to help! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `router.navigate()` into a utility class with a method that takes as parameters the `router` itself and what you want it to do (maybe with optional parameters/default values, or pass it an object) and adds every time by default the `queryParamsHandling`.

Comment: That's where I use my `ExtendedRouter` class, but I cannot deal with the `routerLink` directives. That's where I'm stuck...

Answer (score 0):

In the end I needed a more flexible approach where I could preserve one queryparameter (lang) but drop another (return-url). So eventually I decided to go ahead and write my own `AdvancedRouter` and `advRouterLink`.

Provider that lets you setup your configuration:

```
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";
import { QueryParamsConfig } from "../../interfaces/query-params-config";

export const QUERY_PARAMS_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<QueryParamsConfig>('QueryParamsConfig');
```

Interface for the value of the provider:

```
import { QueryParamsHandling } from "@angular/router";

export interface QueryParamsConfig {
    [key: string]: QueryParamsHandling;
}
```

Configure this provider in the `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    AdvancedRouterModule
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: QUERY_PARAMS_CONFIG, useValue: <QueryParamsConfig>{
      'lang': 'preserve',
      'return': ''
    }
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`AdvancedRouter`

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationBehaviorOptions, NavigationExtras, Params, Router, UrlCreationOptions, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { QueryParamsConfig } from '../../interfaces/query-params-config';
import { QUERY_PARAMS_CONFIG } from '../../providers';
import { UrlWithQueryParams } from './url-with-query-params';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdvancedRouter {

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, @Inject(QUERY_PARAMS_CONFIG) private queryParamsConfig: QueryParamsConfig) {
  }

  public navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras) {
    const newParams = this.computeQueryParameters(this.route.snapshot.queryParams, extras?.queryParams);
    return this.router.navigate(commands, { ...extras, queryParams: newParams });
  }

  public navigateByUrl(url: string | UrlTree, extras?: NavigationBehaviorOptions) {
    // The requested url.
    let urlValue = url instanceof UrlTree
      ? this.router.serializeUrl(url)
      : url;

    // The requested query parameters.
    const requestedParams = this.extractQueryParametersFromUrl(urlValue);

    // Use the current queryparams and requested queryparams
    // to compute the new parameters according to the configuration.
    const newParams = this.computeQueryParameters(this.route.snapshot.queryParams, requestedParams.queryParams);
    const newParamKeys = Object.keys(newParams).filter(key => !['encoder', 'map'].includes(key));
    const newQueryString = newParamKeys.map(key => `${key}=${newParams[key]}`).join('&');

    const newUrl = newParamKeys.length === 0
      ? requestedParams.url
      : `${requestedParams.url}?${newQueryString}`;

    return this.router.navigateByUrl(newUrl, extras);
  }
  
  public createUrlTree(commands: any[], extras?: UrlCreationOptions) {
    const newParams = this.computeQueryParameters(this.route.snapshot.queryParams, extras?.queryParams);
    return this.router.createUrlTree(commands, { ...extras, queryParams: newParams });
  }

  public serializeUrl(url: UrlTree) {
    return this.router.serializeUrl(url);
  }

  private extractQueryParametersFromUrl(url: string) : UrlWithQueryParams {
    if (url.includes('?')) {
      const parts = url.split('?');
      return {
        url: parts[0],
        queryParams: new HttpParams({ fromString: parts[1] })
      };
    } else {
      return {
        url: url,
        queryParams: new HttpParams()
      };
    }
  }

  private containsKey(params: Params, key: string) {
    return Object.keys(params).indexOf(key) > -1;
  }

  private computeQueryParameters(currentParams: Params, requestedParams: Params | null | undefined) {
    // Allow a null object to be passed to this method.
    const newRequestedParams = requestedParams ?? { };

    // Merge the set of keys.
    const allParamKeys = Object.keys({
      ...currentParams,
      ...newRequestedParams
    });

    return <Params>Object.assign({}, ...allParamKeys.map(k => {
        // Compute new value for each Query parameter.
        return {
          key: k,
          value: this.getQueryParameterValue(currentParams, newRequestedParams, k)
        };
      })
      // Remove query parameters to drop.
      .filter(p => p.value !== null)
      // ToDictionary
      .map(p => {
        return { [p.key] : p.value };
      })
    );
  }

  private getQueryParameterValue(currentParams: Params, requestedParams: Params, key: string) {
    switch (this.queryParamsConfig[key]) {
      case 'preserve':
        // Take requested value if present, else take current.

        // Must use containsKey since one may want to explicitly pass a null value for a specific parameter,
        // in order to drop the query parameter specified.
        return Object.keys(requestedParams).indexOf(key) === -1
          ? currentParams[key]
          : requestedParams[key];
      case 'merge':
        if (this.containsKey(currentParams, key)) {
          if (this.containsKey(requestedParams, key)) {
            // Query parameter present in both. Merge both values.
            return `${currentParams[key]},${requestedParams[key]}`;
          } else {
            // Query parameter only present in activated route.
            return currentParams[key];
          }
        } else {
          if (this.containsKey(requestedParams, key)) {
            // Query parameter only present in requested list.
            return requestedParams[key];
          } else {
            // Never occurs
          }
        }
        break;
      default:
        // Default is drop query parameter.
        if (this.containsKey(requestedParams, key)) {
          // If still present in requested list, return this value.
          return requestedParams[key];
        } else {
          // Drop query parameter.
          return null;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

`UrlWithQueryParams`

```
import { Params } from "@angular/router";

export interface UrlWithQueryParams {
    url: string;
    queryParams: Params;
}
```

`AdvancedRouterLinkDirective`

```
import { LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterLinkWithHref, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { AdvancedRouter } from '../../services/advanced-router/advanced-router';

// See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L256

@Directive({selector: 'a[advRouterLink],area[advRouterLink]'})
export class AdvancedRouterLinkDirective extends RouterLinkWithHref {

  constructor(
    private advancedRouter: AdvancedRouter,
    private nativeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    nativeRouter: Router,
    nativeLocationStrategy: LocationStrategy
  ) {
    super(nativeRouter, nativeRoute, nativeLocationStrategy);
  }

  private nativeCommands: any[] = [];

   @Input()
   set advRouterLink(commands: any[] | string | null | undefined) {
     if (commands != null) {
       this.nativeCommands = Array.isArray(commands) ? commands : [commands];
     } else {
       this.nativeCommands = [];
     }
   }

  get urlTree(): UrlTree {
    return this.advancedRouter.createUrlTree(this.nativeCommands, {
      relativeTo: this.relativeTo !== undefined ? this.relativeTo : this.nativeRoute,
      queryParams: this.queryParams,
      fragment: this.fragment,
      queryParamsHandling: '', // Drop queryparams and let the AdvancedRouter do all the work
      preserveFragment: this.attrBoolValue(this.preserveFragment),
    });
  }
  
  private attrBoolValue(s: any) {
    return s === '' || !!s;
  }
}
```

- Github repo: https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-share-buttons/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-router
- Node package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mintplayer/ng-router